# SQL NOT EXISTS in combination with LIKE doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to return those posts with `post_type` = "attachment" , where their `meta_value` (url) doesn't appear in any `post_content` .

For now I'm trying to give the `meta_value` manually, which in this case is a image name `speed1`

I've cheked and there are some posts with the image "speed1.jpg" in the `post_content`.

When I select those WITH the word in the content, it works, the problem arises when I try to select everything else but those with the word in the content, using the query:

```
SELECT 
    i.ID,
    i.post_content,
    i.post_type
FROM
    wp_posts i
WHERE
    i.post_type = 'attachment'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wp_posts p WHERE p.post_type <> 'attachment' AND p.post_content LIKE "%speed1%")
```

this always returns empty. Why?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple CTE that I am using as a crude mock of wp_posts for the following queries -

```sql
WITH wp_posts (ID, post_content, post_type, meta_value) AS (
    SELECT 1, null, 'attachment', 'speed1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, null, 'attachment', 'speed2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, null, 'attachment', 'speed3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'blah blah speed1 blah blah', 'post', null UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'blah blah speed3 blah blah', 'post', null
)
```

which looks like this as a table -

| ID | post_content | post_type | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | speed1 | attachment | speed1 |
| 2 | speed2 | attachment | speed2 |
| 3 | speed3 | attachment | speed3 |
| 4 | blah blah speed1 blah blah | post |  |
| 5 | blah blah speed3 blah blah | post |  |

Your current sub-query in `NOT EXISTS` -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE p.post_type <> 'attachment'
AND p.post_content LIKE "%speed1%"
```

always returns the row with ID 4 from my mock. This means `NOT EXISTS` always returns false as there is a result.

If you change the sub-query to use the meta_value from the outer query you have something which makes more sense -

```sql
SELECT 
    i.ID,
    i.post_content,
    i.post_type
FROM
    wp_posts i
WHERE
    i.post_type = 'attachment'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM wp_posts p
        WHERE p.post_type <> 'attachment'
        AND p.post_content LIKE CONCAT('%', i.meta_value, '%')
    )
```

This returns the row with ID 2 as 'speed2' is not in the post_content of either of the two wp_posts of type 'post'. I hope you are able to make sense of this simple demo.

Answer (score -1):

Could you do something like this

```
SELECT 
    i.ID,
    i.post_content,
    i.post_type
FROM
    wp_posts i
WHERE
    i.post_type = 'attachment'
    AND i.post_content NOT LIKE '%speed1%';
```

Comment: Missing an `AND` between the two conditions in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: this would return me all the attachments, which can't have post_content anyway, so the check for the word in their post_content would always return false (or true if NOT LIKE)

Comment: what i'm trying to return is all the attachments, which value is "speed1" and it doesn't appear in any other post_type's post_content

Comment: @NathanBernard can you tell us which rows you expect in the results?

Answer (score -2):

Literal values must be surrounded by single quotes and not by apostrophes (double quote). Double quote are requested to surround object name in SQL (table name, column name...).

In your query the part :

```
NOT LIKE "%speed1%"
```

Is looking after a column nammed **%speed1%**

It is not the same as comparing to a litteral static value...
I think you will better do :

```
NOT LIKE '%speed1%'
```

Comment: If this was the case then the query would throw an error like `Unknown column ....`. Double quotes work fine for string literals.

Comment: @forpas This is a gotcha of the poor design of MySQL. This will work until someone will add such a columns in the table ! The ISO SQL standard language requires simple quote for all strings and double quote for objects. Of course you can do anything as you see fit, but you shouldn't come crying the day your request fails.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the OP's problem and what you say in your answer: *...Is looking after a column nammed %speed1%* is wrong. The documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html is clear.